# NoMethodError in ProfilesController#show

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I am working with angular and rails, and I can't seem to get the angular application to run inside of my app. I am working with Ruby 2.1.1 and Rails 4.1

Came up with this error just today and I think that I am close to figuring it out:
[image]

```html
angular.module('Waiting', [
        'ngRoute',
        'ng-rails-csrf',
        'templates'
    ]).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/api/parties/:partiesId', {
                templateUrl: '../templates/wait.html',
                controller: 'WaitCtrl'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

```html
angular.module('Waiting')
    .controller('WaitCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http', '$timeout', 'PartyService', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, PartyService) {
      
      $scope.init = function(){
         $scope.partyCount = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10+'];
         $scope.parties = [];
            $scope.formVisible = false;
          $scope.alerts = {};
          $scope.search = {
          };

         PartyService.fetchParties()
          .success($scope.partiesReceived)
         .error($scope.partiesFailed)

       
      };

            $scope.oscillateForm = function(){
                $scope.formVisible = !$scope.formVisible
            };

      $scope.partiesReceived = function(response){
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length ; i++) {
     var each_party = response[i].party

     var partyObject = {
      id: each_party.id,
      name: each_party.name,
      size: each_party.party_count,
      phone: each_party.phone
     }

     $scope.parties.push(partyObject)
    }       
      };

      $scope.partiesFailed = function(response){
       console.log("err");
      };

        $scope.showAll = function(){
          $scope.search = {};
        };

      $scope.addParty = function(isValid){
          if (isValid) {
         PartyService.addAnotherParty($scope.formData)
            .success($scope.partyAdded)
          }
          else {
            console.log("problem with your form mah nigga");
          }
      };

      $scope.partyAdded = function(response){
                console.log(response.party)

                var partyObject = {
                    id: response.party.id,
                    name: response.party.name,
                    size: response.party.party_count,
                    phone: response.party.phone
                }

       $scope.parties.push(partyObject)
       $scope.formData = {};
          $scope.formVisible = false;
          $scope.partyForm.$setPristine();

      };

      $scope.deleteAllParties = function(){
       PartyService.deleteAllParties().success($scope.allPartiesDeleted)
      };

      $scope.allPartiesDeleted = function(response){
       $scope.parties = [];
      };

      $scope.deleteParty = function(index){
       console.log();
       $scope.deleteIndex = index;
       var partyId = $scope.parties[index].id
       PartyService.deleteParty(partyId).success($scope.partyDeleted)
      };

      $scope.partyDeleted = function(response){
       $scope.parties.splice($scope.deleteIndex, 1)
      };

            $scope.sendText = function(index){
                $scope.smsIndex = index;
                var partyId = $scope.parties[index].id
                PartyService.sendText(partyId).success($scope.textSuccessful).error($scope.textFailed) 
                $scope.parties[index].disable = true;  
                $timeout(function(){
                  $scope.parties[index].disable = false;  
              }, 10000);             
            };

            $scope.textSuccessful = function(response){
              $scope.alerts.textSuccesful = true
              $timeout(function(){
                $scope.alerts = {};
              }, 4000);

            };

            $scope.textFailed = function(respn){
               $scope.alerts.textFailed = true
                console.log("IT FAILLLIED");
              $timeout(function(){
                $scope.alerts = {};
              }, 4000);
            };

            $scope.alertsExist = function(){
              var keys = Object.keys($scope.alerts).length
              if (keys == 0) {
                return false
              }
              else {
                return true
              }
            };


        $scope.init();
    }]);
```

parties_controller.rb

```html
class PartiesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json, :xml

  def index
    @parties = current_business.parties
    respond_with(@parties)
  end

  def create
    @party = Party.create(name: params[:name], party_count: params[:size], phone: params[:phone], user_id: current_business.id)
    respond_with(@party)
  end

  def destroy
    @party = Party.find(params[:id])
    @party.destroy
    render :json => 'Success'
  end

  def destroy_all
    Party.destroy_all(:business_id => current_business.id)
    render :json => 'Success'
  end

end
```

Below is what I put into my parties/index.html.erb file to just to see if I could get the functionality working:

```html
<div class="container" ng-app="Waiting">
 {{PartyService}}
 {{partiesReceived}}
 </div>
```

```html
   scope :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    post '/send_text/:id' => 'send_text#send_text_message'
    resources :parties
    get '/parties/destroy/all'  => 'parties#destroy_all'
  end
```

Thanks ahead of time for the help!

Comment: Does your User mode have an attribute called `profile_name`?

Comment: profile_name is not present in my user model.

Comment: That's your problem. Don't do `User.find_by_profile_name` in your `ProfileController#show` action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def User.find_by_profile_name(profile_name)
  self.find_by(username: profile_name)
end`

add this method on your app/models/user.rb

Comment: the only thing is, is that it shouldn't be hitting the user model at all, it has its own controllers and so forth? I am confused!

Comment: Your profile_controller.rb is calling the method `find_by_profile_name' in the User models (app/model/user.rb). Can you show me the User models?

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted

Comment: Cool man that seems to have solved my issue. Now I just need to get my angular working correctly

Answer (score 0):

```html
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader 
  
  
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:login]
  attr_accessor :login  
         validates :username, 
         :uniqueness => {
           :case_sensitive => false 
         }
          
          
          has_many :statuses
          has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy 
          has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
          has_many :purchases, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "buyer_id"
         
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup 
  if login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions).where(["username = :value OR lower(email) = lower(:value)", { :value => login }]).first
    else
        where(conditions).first
      end
end

def full_name
    if self.name.blank?
      self.email
    else
      self.name
    end
  end
end
```